# How can you use secret variables from a linked variable group in an Azure Powershell task in an Azure Release pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an Azure **Release** pipeline that I've built using the GUI in Azure DevOps. There is a stage that has a linked variable group (Release scope) with a secret variable in the variable group. The stage has an agent job with an Azure Powershell task that runs a script file. That script file references the secret variable using the syntax `$env:MYSECRETVARIABLE` but the value is null. When I add an Azure Powershell task for debugging that runs `Get-ChildItem -Path Env:\`, I can see that all the non-secret variables in the variable group are mapped but the secret variable is not. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested to get the secret variable in the variable group in azure powershell task, just use the syntax of `$(varibaleName)` to work.

Test with inline script:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Test with Script File:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Hugh. In your example, how are you referencing the -Name and -Age parameters in your script file?

Comment: I added my powershell script to the answer.Please view it.

Comment: I got it working based on your example. A big part of my confusion was that the Define variables article (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) shows that you should be using environment variables for secret variables, which I did for Build Pipelines and it worked fine. In Release Pipelines they apparently need to be passed into the script as a parameter. So I had to modify the script to work with both environment variables and parameters since Build and Release pipelines work differently in this regard. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To help others who may fell into this trap.
With Azure release pipelines it only works if you map the secret variable into environment. Passing the secret variable via arguments will not work.
Tried out a multiple variants, with inline- or file-script, with secret pipeline variable or secret linked variable group, in the end, what counts is the environment mapping. Here you are:

The variable group with the secret ***spPwd***
[image]

And how it is passed into the script, no matter if inline or file, here ***ENVPWD***
[image]

Good luck to all the poor ones struggling with azure pipelines :)